# LG G2 screen isn't working in partial areas

Tags: touchscreen, lg-g2

So the other day I dropped my LG G2 from about 5 feet high and it smacked the ground. The screen was not damaged and everything looked fine with the phone, but when I started using it that wasn't the case. About 75% of my screen works when I touch it but a certain section of it does not. It isn't cracked or anything and you can see everything on screen, only the touch screen will not work in a certain section on my phone. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

The (very small) cable that runs from the digitizer (the thing that reads your touches) to the motherboard (the part that does the thinking) was probably either damaged or knocked loose.

ifixit.com has a section on do-it-yourself hardware repairs or, it's time to find a repair depot.